# Selecting distinct records

Tags: postgresql

I have a user relation to address (1 to 1).

So the address has two types which is a `type` column.

One is the `VerifiedAddress` and the other one is the `SearchAddress`.

So the user who had verified his address has two entries in the addresses table.

In case you wonder why is that, the reason is that user can go to a travel and change the `SearchAddress` but the `VerifiedAddress` remains the same.

I'm trying to find all the users who haven't got verified their address. I have some user list from which I know who has verified address and who hasn't got it.

This is what I have tried the last, not exactly what I wanted :

```
select id from addresses
where user_id in (8112, 18620, 23, 19668, 10212)
and type = 'VerifiedAddress';
```

Gives me all the verified users, but if I change the `type != VerifiedAddress` I still get the same results because users who have verified their address have two entries in a addresses table, this time I get the user_ids from the `SearchAddress`.

How can I get this data from addresses table?

**Note:** `SearchAddress` can be null as well as `VerifiedAddress`. Naturally people who don't have searchaddress don't have the verified as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a left anti-join. You want all users who *don't* have a verified address. So you do a left join to find all users and whether they *do* have a verified address, then discard all the ones that have a verified address.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses a
ON (users.id = a.user_id AND a.type = 'VerifiedAddress')
WHERE a.user_id IS NULL;
```

This may be easier to understand when expressed with `NOT EXISTS` as:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM addresses a
  WHERE users.id = a.user_id
  AND a.type = 'VerifiedAddress'
)
```

both of which will optimize to the same query plan, in general.

Comment: thanks Craig, this was what I was looking for, does the using of aliases like addresses a, have any impact on the performance?

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow: No measurable influence.